# unable to serve pyramid app

Tags: python, pyramid, gunicorn

I'm pretty inexperienced with gunicorn. I have it installed within a virtual env and am trying to serve a pyramid app with the following:

```
env/bin/gunicorn --pid /home/staging/gunicorn.pid --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 pyzendoc:main
```

However everytime a request is sent I get the following trace from gunicorn

```
2013-10-30 14:16:20 [1284] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/staging/api/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I'm guessing that main in the gunicorn refers to the main method in pyramids **init** but that method takes (global_config, **settings) as args so I think that maybe gunicorn is somehow looking at the wrong method. Has anyone seen anything similar before?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invocation `pyzendoc:main` is expecting to find a callable that accepts an `(environ, start_response)` signature, as a WSGI app, which you don't have until `main(global_conf, **settings)` returns one. A better option is to use `gunicorn_paster`, as shown [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn-paster).

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your reply. I've tried the gunicorn_paster now both invoking directly with the same options as above and specifying the server as gunicorn in the .ini file as was in the link. The gunicorn log and netstat now all show that gunicorn is listening on 127.0.0.1:8000 but if I do a local curl nothing is registering

Comment: Well does it work with pserve? I mean with waitress as the server, like in the pyramid tutorials.

Comment: Hi michael. Your first answer was the right one. I had some other config issues. Thanks for the help.